# Show that all terms of this sequence are integers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

> The sequence is given by the following formula:
> $$(n+3)a_{n+2}=(6n+9)a_{n+1}-na_n$$
> with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=2$. Show that all terms of this sequence are integers.

---

I have an original solution for this problem (next, will be briefly outlining that).

It first determines a generating function $\big(f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \big)$ and finds its explicit form in some neighborhood of $0$. Namely,
$$f(x)=\frac{1-x-\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}}{2x},  \ \ |x|<3- \sqrt 2$$
Then, says this function satisfies the quadratic equation $xt^2-(1-x)t+1=0$.

After some operations with it, they end up with obtaining another recurrence formula for $(a_n)$ as follows:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n + \sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}$$
Obviously, an easy induction will complete the proof now.

---

However, I'd like to know if one could approach this by some other methods/thinking. The reason why I'm curious is that this solution gets quite a messy appearance while finding the form of $f(x)$ and I don't think this beautiful problem has no other rather attractive approach.

> **By the way**, the OS says proving that it's an increasing sequence is an easy job and skipping that part. Maybe it is really easy but I'm troubled to show...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is from IMC 2019 day 1 problem 4 and generating functions approach is indeed the official solution as well (https://www.imc-math.org.uk/?year=2019&section=problems&item=prob4s).

Comment: Your generating function, and subsequent recurrence formula both smell like Catalan numbers. I would look for more inspiration here, for example, by looking for a bijective proof to some objects: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @Sil - Yeah you're right. It seems like you participated in that, didn't you? :)

Comment: Not really, just found it by [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(n%2B3)a_%7Bn%2B2%7D%3D(6n%2B9)a_%7Bn%2B1%7D-na_n%24&p=1)

Comment: In fact, these are known as "Large Schroder Numbers": http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C6%2C22%2C90&language=english&go=Search

Comment: @Sil - Oh I see :)

Comment: @AlexR. - "The number of perfect matchings in a triangular grid of n squares (n = 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ...)" (copied from the page you shared) . Does it try to mean

$$1$$

$$2$$

$$3,4,5,6$$

$$7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 ...$$

I think I didn't get it... Sorry I couldn't make it look like a triangle :)